# Factorisation of algebraic expressions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

Can this expression be factored? 
$$a^2b - a^2c - ac^2 - ab^2 - b^2c + 2abc.$$

It doesn't work if I try the normal method.

Comment: What is the "normal method"?

Comment: Normal as in factorisation by grouping, or trial and error.

Comment: Treat it as a quadratic in $a$ for example $a^2(b - c) - a(c^2 + b^2- 2bc) - b^2c$ and draw your own conclusions.

Comment: Nice question. $\;\!$

Comment: no $b c^2?....$

Comment: I did the quadratic way but it didn't work

Comment: are you sure that there is no typo?